# Non capturing group included in capture?

Tags: regex

This text

```
"dhdhd89(dd)"
```

Matched against this regex

```
.+?(?:\()
```

..returns "**dhdhd89(**".

Why is the start parenthesis included in the capture?
Two different tools, as well as the .NET Regex class, returns the same result. So I gather there is something I don't understand about this.

The way I read my regex is.

- Match any character, at least one occurrence. As few as possible.
- The matched string should be followed by a start parenthesis, but not to be included in the capture.

I can find workaround, but I still want to know what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn the non-capturing group to positive lookahead assertion.

```
.+?(?=\()
```

`.+?` non-greedy match of one or more characters followed by an opening parenthesis. Assertions won't match any characters but asserts whether a match is possible or not. But the non-capturing group will do the matching operation.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lA6rS5/3)

Comment: Yes, I read the example wrong. I thought "(?:" was how to define a noncapturing group. Expresso Identified it as such. But replacing the : for = made it all work.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this **negation based regex** to capture only text before a literal `(`:

```
^([^(]+)
```

When you use:

```
.+?(?:\()
```

Regex engine does match `(` after initial text but it just doesn't return that in a captured group to you.

Comment: You may call it workaround but **negation based regex** are preferred over `non-greedy` quantifier `.+?` due to no backtracking and efficiency.

Comment: Appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You havn't defined capture groups then I guess you display the whole match (group 0), you can do:

```
(.+?)(?:\()
```

and the string you want is in group 1

or use lookahead as @AvinashRaj said.